# Attaching ngClass to ngFor items depending on index from another ngFor

Tags: angular, ng-class, ngfor

So I encountered something odd.

I have two lists generated by ngFor. The first one's got clickable items. The other one's items are just supposed to adapt different classes depending on events in the first list.

What happens is that all items in the clickable list but the last are disabled once I attach the ngClass.

Any ideas of what could have gone wrong?

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of items; let index = index">
   <div [ngClass]="{'some-class': index !== chosenIndex,'some-other-class': index === chosenIndex}">
      <em>{{i.name}}</em>
   </div>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let o of objects; let i = index">
  <div> {{o.title}} (click)="viewInfo(o,i)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
viewInfo (o: Object, i: number) {
  this.object = o;
  this.chosenIndex = i;
}
```

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Disabled as in cursor: pointer is no longer working, and they are not clickable.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?